# r sum numbers by character and date

Tags: r, sum, aggregate, cbind

I'm trying sum the number values for each month with this data:

mydata

```
char  numb date
cat   1    21-01-01
cat   1    21-01-01
cat   1    21-03-01
bird  2    21-01-01
bird  2    21-01-01
bird  2    21-02-01
dog   3    21-01-01
dog   3    21-01-01
dog   3    21-02-01
dog   3    21-02-01
dog   3    21-03-01
dog   3    21-03-01
```

. . . and I can't seem to aggregate and cbind with a sum that I want for each character by month.  Would result in:

```
char  numb  date
cat   2     21-01-01
cat   1     21-02-01
bird  4     21-01-01
bird  2     21-02-01
dog   6     21-01-01
dog   6     21-02-01
dog   6     21-03-01
```

I know how to use numcolwise(sum) to sum the numbers by character or date, but not both.  (I'm also kinda vague on how dplyr can be used to group and gather.) Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By using `dplyr` or `plyr` or `data.table`,

## Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "char  numb date
cat   1    21-01-01
cat   1    21-01-01
cat   1    21-03-01
bird  2    21-01-01
bird  2    21-01-01
bird  2    21-02-01
dog   3    21-01-01
dog   3    21-01-01
dog   3    21-02-01
dog   3    21-02-01
dog   3    21-03-01
dog   3    21-03-01", header = T)
```

## Code `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(char, date) %>%
  summarize(numb = sum(numb))

  char  date      numb
  <chr> <chr>    <int>
1 bird  21-01-01     4
2 bird  21-02-01     2
3 cat   21-01-01     2
4 cat   21-03-01     1
5 dog   21-01-01     6
6 dog   21-02-01     6
7 dog   21-03-01     6
```

## `plyr`

```
ddply(df, c("char", "date"), summarise, numb = sum(numb))

  char     date numb
1 bird 21-01-01    4
2 bird 21-02-01    2
3  cat 21-01-01    2
4  cat 21-03-01    1
5  dog 21-01-01    6
6  dog 21-02-01    6
7  dog 21-03-01    6
```

## `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[, .(numb = sum(numb)), by = c("char", "date")]

   char     date numb
1:  cat 21-01-01    2
2:  cat 21-03-01    1
3: bird 21-01-01    4
4: bird 21-02-01    2
5:  dog 21-01-01    6
6:  dog 21-02-01    6
7:  dog 21-03-01    6
```

Comment: That seems to work!  Thanks so-much.  (When I ran the dplyr code I got one total number rather than a number for each character)